# @Webfluxtest behaves differently than Integration Test

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this Webflux controller-implementation:

```java
public Mono<ResultDto> translate(final Flux<String> body,
                                 final String userId) {
    return userRepository.findByUserId(userId) // returns language obj.
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .switchIfEmpty(
                    Mono.defer(() -> {
                                final Language language = Language.of(userId);
                                log.info("Mono Defer");
                                return userRepository.save(language); //returns language obj.
                            })
                            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
            .log("after switch if empty")
            .map(language -> translatorService.createTranslator(language))
            .map(cipher -> body.map(language::translate))
            .flatMap(flux -> proxyService.relayEntry(flux));
}
```

This code behaves always correct for `@WebfluxTest` and for integration tests with `@TestContainers`.

e.g.

```
2023-05-03T09:34:11.414+02:00  INFO 66397 --- [     parallel-1] after switch if empty                    : onSubscribe(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.SwitchIfEmptySubscriber)
2023-05-03T09:34:11.415+02:00  INFO 66397 --- [     parallel-1] after switch if empty                    : request(unbounded)
2023-05-03T09:34:11.418+02:00  INFO 66397 --- [oundedElastic-1] c.c.b.e.api.TranslatorV1ControllerImpl      : Mono Defer
2023-05-03T09:34:11.418+02:00  INFO 66397 --- [oundedElastic-1] after switch if empty                    : onNext(com.company.team.service.user.User@5418b6f8)
2023-05-03T09:34:12.590+02:00  INFO 66397 --- [oundedElastic-1] after switch if empty                    : onComplete()
```

But if I remove the 2nd `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))` from `Mono.defer(()` the `@WebfluxTest` behaves the same but no longer the real integration test.

after `switchIfEmpty()` the code will be always executed on the main thread group for the case that `findByUserId` returns an empty Mono.

```
2023-05-03T09:41:16.864+02:00  INFO 67894 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] after switch if empty
```

If `findByUserId` does not return an empty mono its correctly executed on **boundedElastic-1**.

If I remove the first `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` right after `.findByUserId(userId)` and leave the last one and `.findByUserId(userId)` returns an empty mono then the **"Mono defer"** string will be on the other hand on the reactor main thread while **"after switch if empty"** is working on **boundedElastic-1**.

So as of now using two times `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` behaves in all cases as it is expected. So no real todo here.

But I am curious and wondering why `@Webfluxtest` and the integration test of this endpoint behave differently.

Any idea?